# OSX App Unrecognized Selector error when downloaded image from a when downloaded image from a JSON web service

Tags: objective-c, json, macos, nsdata, nsimage

In my Mac app I am getting Data from hey JSON web service and one of the fields is an image. When I do a `NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"profileImageDataString"] );` I see all of the data and it is correct. And I can also put it in a NSURL object like this `NSURL *imgUrl = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"profileImageDataString"];` and it is still correct. But when I try this `NSData *imgData =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];` or this `NSImage *userImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];`I get the error unrecognized selector sent to instance. If I put the data in a NSString, two thirds is cut off at the end.

I am trying to save the Image data from the Jason web service into a text file to that later it can be loaded into a NSImage on in a user settings view.

Someone tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong?

This is the value of profileImageDataString that is returned by the web service;

```
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
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string seems to be a base64 encoded string representation of an image.

Try to create an `NSData` object from the string and the image from the data.

```
NSString *imgDataString = [dict objectForKey:@"profileImageDataString"];
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:imgDataString options:0];
NSImage *userImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

Comment: When I tried that I get the same error here NSString *imgPath = [dict objectForKey:@"profileImageDataString"]; I was able to get it into a nsstring earlier but when I did only the first third of the values from the json web service were present. It is like the nsstring is not big enough to hold that data.

Comment: please update you question posting a sample `profileImageDataString`.

Comment: I changed the answer suggesting a way to convert the string to data

Comment: Thanks Vadian, I don't know why but the value becomes an array when I get it. This works; `code` NSArray *imgPath = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"profileImageDataString"];
             NSData *imgData = [imgPath[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSImage *userImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imgData]; But now the userImage is nil when I NSLog it. I suspect that may be because of a problem with the data itself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: **don't use** `valueForKeyPath:`, use always `objectForKey:`.  `valueForKeyPath:` is a special key value coding method for providing a key path for nested objects which returns an array.

Comment: PS: Also use the `initWithBase64EncodedString` method, the string data is correct.

Comment: @inosu812 nothing is converted; if you get an array out when accessing that key, then your JSON had an array.

Comment: @Tommy: It's more likely a misuse of `valueForKeyPath`

Comment: The answer lies in the initWithBase64EncodedString. This works. I don't kow how I wasn't seeing it after you put it there. I guess I have looked too long. `code` NSString *imgDataString = [dict objectForKey:@"profileImageDataString"];
            NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:imgDataString options:0];
            NSImage *userImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imgData]; `code` Thanks everyone.

Comment: @vadian inosu812's response was that when he tries your code, using `objectForKey:`, he gets the error. So I discounted the possibility that he's calling `valueForKey:` on an array and therefore getting an array.

Answer (score 0):

> And I can also put it in a NSURL object like this NSURL *imgUrl = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"profileImageDataString"]; and it is still correct.

You haven't got an `NSURL` object. You've got an `NSString` object. Declaring that your pointer refers to an `NSURL` and using the untyped getter `valueForKeyPath:` (or, even, much more correctly, `objectForKey:`) does not change the type of the object.

To convert a string to a URL use `+[NSURL URLWithString:]`. But what you're showing us isn't a URL. So why try to make it one at all?

> But when I try this NSData *imgData =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl]; or this NSImage *userImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];I get the error unrecognized selector sent to instance.

That's because you're supplying an `NSString`, which does not implement the same selectors as an `NSURL`.

> If I put the data in a NSString, two thirds is cut off at the end.

No it isn't; however when you log any object, all you get is enough information to help in debugging. Using `NSLog` is not intended to be a way to store the same amount of data in another form, or indeed to do anything strictly well defined other than help you to debug.

Get your string, use the approach as suggested by vadian.